# Why running lldb with HomeBrew Python 2 installed produces ImportError and NameErrors?

Tags: terminal, macos, homebrew, python

I had upgraded `vim` with HomeBrew to version 7.4.1952 on OS X 10.11.6. It installed python 2 as a dependency package (Summarized parts of output is shown by `...`):

```
$ brew upgrade vim
...
==> Installing vim dependency: python
   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11: 4,949 files, 66.6M
...
```

Now when I try to run `lldb`, it produces ImportError and NameErrors:

```
$ lldb myExecutableFile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python/lldb/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
(lldb) target create "myExecutableFile"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
...
Current executable set to 'myExecutableFile' (x86_64).
(lldb)
```

This is my `$PATH` in zsh shell:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

How can I solve these errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed `six` module with `pip` python package manager and it solves the problem:

```
$ pip install six
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six
Successfully installed six-1.10.0

$ lldb myExecutableFile
(lldb) target create "myExecutableFile"
Current executable set to 'myExecutableFile' (x86_64).
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Apple `lldb` (from `/usr/bin/lldb`) expects and requires `/usr/bin/python`. Unfortunately, it doesn't use this absolute path to invoke it, but just `python`.

Thus, with a Python 2 also installed by Homebrew inside `/usr/local/bin` which is in the front of your `PATH` the Apple `lldb` gets an unexpected Python 2 which may introduce errors like missing expected packages or worse.

The safe thing is thus to call `lldb` with a different `PATH`:

```
$ PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH lldb ...
```

Or even configure an alias or wrapper script, e.g.:

```
$ alias lldb='PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH lldb'
```